# How can I add a top and bottom border to specific columns while implementing jspdf print in Angular?

Tags: angular, jspdf

I need to implement jspdf print with certain conditions

1. Some specific column need to bordered top and bottom
2. Example image provided if any suggestion its very thankful[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6mRS.png)

The above image showing underlines in some amounts I want to implement these structure.

I need to implement jspdf print with certain conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
willDrawCell: function(data) {
    if (data.row.section === "body") {
       doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
       doc.setLineWidth(0.2);
       // draw bottom border
        doc.line(
            data.cell.x,
            data.cell.y + data.cell.height,
            data.cell.x + data.cell.width,
            data.cell.y + data.cell.height
        );
        // draw top border
        doc.line(
            data.cell.x + data.cell.width,
            data.cell.y,
            data.cell.x,
            data.cell.y
        );
        // draw left border
        doc.line(
            data.cell.x,
            data.cell.y + data.cell.height,
            data.cell.x,
            data.cell.y
        );
        // draw right border
        doc.line(
            data.cell.x + data.cell.width,
            data.cell.y,
            data.cell.x + data.cell.width,
            data.cell.y + data.cell.height
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).